# The Rook Conjecture: arrangement of $p$ primes being distinct $\pmod{p}$ through $p^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

For any prime $p$, divide $[1,p^2]$ into $p$ equal intervals of length $p$, so that the first interval is $[1,p]$, the next $[p+1,2p]$, and so on. It is definitely unproven but seems likely that there will always be a prime in every one of these intervals. It is even probably true when you substitute any natural $n$ in place of the prime $p$ above.

I've noticed a stricter condition that seems to hold. If you divide $p^2$ as described above, not only will there be a prime in every interval of length $p$, but there will always be at least one way to select those primes such that no value is repeated $\bmod{p}$.

A good name for this might be the Rook Conjecture, as this is equivalent to saying that if you number the squares of a $p\times p$ sized chessboard, there is always at least one way to place $p$ rooks on prime-numbered squares yet have no rooks share a rank or file.

**Examples**

$p=3,\qquad S=\{3,5,7\}\equiv\{0,2,1\} \pmod{3}$
$p=5,\qquad S=\{5,7,11,19,23\}\equiv\{0,2,1,4,3\} \pmod{5}$

etc.

I've verified this for $p\leq 1000$. As usual, I am curious whether this is a known result and/or where to look for related work, and of course any counterexamples should they exist. I'm also curious whether this result seems to others to be surprising, or expected; I'm having a hard time deciding the answer for myself.

Comment: Check 'Bertrand's Postulate'.

Comment: Did you also check it for the positive integers in the range $[2,1000]$ ?

Comment: @SL_MathGuy This is not enough, but maybe Opperman's conjecture implies it which states that $g_n\le \sqrt{p_n}$ for sufficiently large $n$

Comment: @Peter If I understand you, that's not directly applicable, since you could only hit every value $\bmod n$ when $n$ is prime.

Comment: @Trevor I also see the problem, and Opperman's conjecture is of course open. Shall I try to implement an efficient pari/gp code ?

Comment: (+1) and a favorite-question-vote by the way. In fact an interesting conjecture.

Comment: I don't know if this helps. Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions states that if $a$ and $d$ are co-primes, then there are infinitely many primes of the form $a + nd$.In other words, there are infinitely many primes that are congruent to $mod (d)$.

Comment: your first sentence is for any integer $n$.

Comment: 5 is 2 mod 3, so remainders that are 1 mod 3, can only be prime in ranges for multipliers not 1 mod 3, remainders that  2 mod 3 can't occur in multipliers that are 2 mod 3 ... remainders that are 0 mod 3 will not happen in multipliers that are 0 mod 3...

Comment: Lastly if $p$ and $p+m$ are primes then the first $1+\lfloor {p\over m} \rfloor$ primes chosen can stay the same potentially, because they'll be in the same multiples of $p+m$ unless not strictly increasing by the difference in the primes.  in your 5 case we can shift the  1 and 3 down to the previous multiple wrapping remainders, to get (5,4,?,2,....) for 7 potentially.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you'll find any counterexamples if you haven't found any up to $1000$. On the random model of the primes, the expected number of $p$-tuples covering the remainders in this way is about $\frac{p!}{\log^pp}$, which grows quite quickly. If there were systematic effects preventing these tuples, they should have shown up in your data.

Comment: @joriki there is always at least 1 class left out in every multiplier.

Comment: @Trevor  It is not difficult to prove that for $n\ge 2$ (not necessarily prime), in every above interval there is at least one prime, if the prime gap $g$ after some prime $p$ satisfies $g\le \lfloor \sqrt{p} \rfloor$ for $p\ge 127$ , since for $n\le 127$, there is always a prime. This has not been proven, but is almost surely the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GRH neither implies that there is a prime in $[p^2-p,p^2]$ nor that the least prime $\equiv a\bmod p$ is $\le p^2$. Thus your conjecture is very strong and there is no fear to use the random model for the primes.

You are saying that for some permutation $\sigma$ of $[1,p-1]$, all the $np+\sigma(n),n\in [1,p-1]$ are primes.

The *probability* that they are all primes is  $$\approx\prod_{n=1}^{p-1}\frac1{\log( np+\sigma(n))} \approx \frac{C}{\log^{p-1} p}$$ the *probability* that no permutation works is $$\approx (1-\frac{C}{\log^{p-1} p})^{(p-1)!}\approx \exp(- \frac{C (p-1)!}{\log^{p-1-\epsilon} p}) $$

The *probability* that no permutation works for some $p\ge k$ is $$f(k)\le \sum_{p\ge k}\exp(- \frac{C (p-1)!}{\log^{p-1-\epsilon} p})$$
Since the series converges and $$\lim_{k\to \infty} f(k)=0$$
then the **random model predicts that your conjecture holds for $p$ large enough**.

(Why did I use the $\approx$ symbol ? Because the random model is case specific : we can and we should take in account the "congruences constraints" before assuming all the implied random variables are independent, which is what we need to simplify everything. Here I don't have any good argument for why this computation does take in account the relevant congruence constraints.)